# How to reuse the same content in HTML

Tags: html

I am working on a web page.
All I need is to reuse the text on pages.
For example, if there is a home button on top right corner, then the same
button should appear in all the pages of html.

Comment: You mean, like a template? This is usually done on server side, although there is some experimental client side technology in the making.. But for the time being look into PHP and such

Comment: Do you need something like templates/master pages

Comment: no man. Like when you use youtube, on left top corner there's always a text saying 'YouTube'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some scripting.

Assuming you cant do server side scripting, you could write a javascript/jquery method in a file called Navigation.js like this

```
$(function(){
   $('#navigation').html("<button>home</button>")
})
```

if you include this js on every page, it will look for an element with the id "navigation" and add a button with the text "home" into it.

Update to do similar with css

```
#navigation::before{
    content:'Home';
    background:'red'
}
```

The css above will create a red element with the text "home" in it on every page that has an element with the id navigation.
The downside: since this is a css pseudo element, it is not part of the dom, and you cannot bind click events to it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this thing using css. I downloaded this template http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page196/wp-digital-download#shout and even that has a fixed text named 'WP Digital Download' which appears on all the pages.

Comment: @NameetNameet Just find these "<h1>Wp Digital<span>Download</span></h1>" on pages and replace with your own text then. But this goal is not related with your question btw.

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk I know I could, but I want to learn how to do it.

Comment: @NameetNameet It depends on what you intend to do with the elements you are creating.
You can use CSS to creat ::before and ::after elements, which an have content and style, but once rendered they cannot be changed with things like javascript.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need server side or client side scripts. You can also have limited abilities with CSS [content](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/). As an old-fashioned workaround, with pure HTML, you can use Iframes or frames.